# Problem installing ext-sodium * for installing lcobucci/jwt 4.3.0 and kreait/firebase-tokens 4.3.0 for laravel project

Tags: php

createtoken(""); is not working in my laravel project... where I have deleted vendor file and done composer install : I am getting :

Problem 1

- lcobucci/jwt is locked to version 4.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- lcobucci/jwt 4.3.0 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
  Problem 2
- lcobucci/jwt 4.3.0 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
- kreait/firebase-tokens 4.3.0 requires lcobucci/jwt ^4.3.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0].
- kreait/firebase-tokens is locked to version 4.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
  then i did
- `sudo pecl install libsodium`
  but I am getting :

> janammaharjan@Janams-MacBook-Air laravel-uat % sudo pecl install
> libsodium WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols,
> use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update pecl/libsodium
> requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0, version <= 8.0.99), installed version
> is 8.2.4 No valid packages found install failed

I have php version 8.2.4

I tried installing xampp with php 8.0.28 but it is not helping can anyone help me on this ?

while doing `sudo pecl install -f libsodium` I am getting :

```
configure: error: wrong libsodium lib version (< 1.0.8) or lib not found ERROR: `/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/libsodium/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config' failed
```